# Unable to start Cloud stack 4.4 instances due to For Input String "MON"

Tags: apache-cloudstack

I have just setup my Cloudstack 4.4 and everything was fine but received an error called **"For Input String "MON" "**

My console proxy VM and Secondary storage VM are both up and running.

I have tried to reinstall a clean version of cloudstack 4.4 and still have the same error.

Before i migrate my 2 cloudstack machine from one environment to another, the CS 4.4 was working fine. Now, the ip address changes but i have changed the required following to this new environment.

At the new environment, after i set it up, everything was fine when i click the "infrastructure" word and there was no alert. Then i added a few iso into the cloud through the template section. After that i started to get that error. I have also tried to restart both the Xen and CS 4.4 but to no avail.

I will be posting pictures of the error below.

XenServer 6.2 with NFS server

Primary storage: /export/primary

Secondary storage: /export/secondary

Xen01 ip : 172.16.90.60

CS 4.4 ip : 172.16.90.61

Both console proxy VM and Secondary storage vm seems to be up and running fine.

Because of this error, I could not add new VMs into my cloud.
Anyone having the same problem?

Pictures link below (because i could not post images)

```
https://115.66.5.90/manage/shares/Photos/Infrastructure-For-input-string-Mon.jpeg?__c=3070092169409312931

https://115.66.5.90/manage/shares/Photos/Unable-to-start-instance-due-to-for-input-string-Mon.jpeg?__c=3070092169409312931
```

i have tried reformatting the whole cloudstack again to make sure i make nothing wrong and now i have the error.

For Input String “Thu” Problem only arise after i add the first ISO image under template. I am quite certain to say that this error could be the Day variable of java. Ip address are the same.

However i still have not find any solution yet.

This is the server management log file that i have extracted.

```
https://115.66.5.90/manage/shares/Photos/management-server%28Latest%29.log?__c=2045857882451466336
```

For the Java, i have not do anything to it before. But i have just updated it to 1.7

Java version "1.7.0_67"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)

Comment: can you edit your post and explain in more detail when did you start to get this error. Had you a fully functional installation of CS 4.4? What changed around the time that the error started to appear?

Comment: If you require more information, i could allow you to connect into my cloud and see it's error. my email would be weiquan38@hotmail.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you manage to solve this?

The error occurs due to a issue with the system templates.

Upgrading your system templates to the latest and deleting the old system vms so new ones are spun up should fix the issue.

Comment: Wooop thanks for the solution! I didnt not solve it however i fell back to 4.3 on my machines. Will try 4.4 with the new templates. Thanks!!!

Comment: Cool! 4.3.1 is a good place to stay in my view if you want the most stable system and don't require any of the new features added in 4.4